# How to get api key from steamcommunity.com?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I am working now, my site will  connection with  steamcommunity.com. I have completed the install steamcommunity. I have account also. But I am not get a API key. But one thing all tutorials will say follow this [link](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) and get API key. But my account in this link always show

```
Access Denied
You will be granted access to Steam Web API keys when you have games in your      Steam account.

Visit Steam Support for more information
```

I have followed this [link](https://steamcommunity.com/dev)

How can I get API key and open id from this site?

Comment: It says that you haven't any games in your Steam Account. You need to have at least one game in your Steam Account to use the API

Comment: ya i have a already one game in my account .its a free game

Comment: Free games don't count.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I was trying to use the [invisnik/laravel-steam-auth](https://packagist.org/packages/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth) Laravel package to implement a steam auth system for my project.

By the time my steam account had ZERO purchases :D
First, I though it will be enough to buy just "any" item from their store, so obviously I've purchased a $1.99 game but nothing happened!

Then I saw somewhere that "maybe" a TOTAL of $5 spending will activate the API Key for my account. I gave it a try and bought two more games ($2.99 + $0.49). 
Now my total spending have exceeded $5 ( $1.99 + $2.99 + $0.49 = $5.47) and the API Key got activated instantly !!

Answer (score 3):

As mytuny stated, you need to have spent more than $5 on your account to obtain an Api key.

There are a few features that are disabled until you have spent $5 on Steam.

You can see the restrictions here.
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-iagk-7663